# clip-path polygon over another

Tags: html, css, angular, clip-path

In my CSS code, I'm using 2 clip-path `polygon()`, but the second that is just under the first won't be stick to the bottom left corner of the first div. Here is a screenshot...

[image: Screenshot]

... and my code:

**CSS**

```
.container1 {
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('/assets/images/esron.gif');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    clip-path: polygon(0px 40vh,100vw 50vh,100vw 0,0 0);
}

.cd-container {
    width: auto;
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Ewert', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;

    clip-path: polygon(0px 10vh,100vw 20vh,100vw -30vh,0 0)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container1">

</div>

<div class="cd-container">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `clip-path` doesn't change the hitbox of divs, it only puts a mask on top of them. You could solve this problem by wrapping `.container1` and set it's background-color to white:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container1"></div>
</div>
<div class="cd-container">
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: white;
}
...
```